# Data structure list that holds two items and can return one by the other

Tags: c#, list

I have a `dictionary` that holds `int` as a key and `string` as a value.

I can get `string` by giving it the `int`. What I want is a data structure that will enable me that AND the ability to get `int` by giving it the `string`.

So I want it to work both ways. What do I use for that?

Oh, and I know for a fact that every int and every string are unique.

Comment: Sounds like a multimap to me: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/multimap/

Comment: If there's no built-in type, you could probably pretty easily create a class which internally has two `IDictionary<K, V>` properties and exposes common `IDictionary<K, V>` operations (not sure if you could successfully implement the interface itself with this object, but it's worth a try).  Those operations would just have overloads for each generic type.  So two indexers, two `Add()` methods, etc.  Implementing the actual interface *might* be doable as something like: `DoubleDictionary<K, V> : IDictionary<K, V>, IDictionary<V, K>`

Comment: @duffymo Isn't a multimap corresponding to an ILookup<> implementation? That wouldn't solve the problem.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, a multimap allows the special case of looking up values by key and key by value, as long as both are 1:1.

Comment: i don't think so, because ````Lookup<>```` is an aggregator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build a custom data type that internally uses two dictionaries, one `Dictionary<int, string>` and one `Dictionary<string, int>`.

```
class TwoWayDictionary<T1, T2>
{
    IDictionary<T1, T2> dic1 = new Dictionary<T1, T2>();
    IDictionary<T2, T1> dic2 = new Dictionary<T2, T1>();

    public T2 this[T1 key]
    {
        get
        {
            return dic1[key];
        }
        set
        {
            dic1[key] = value;
            dic2[value] = key;
        }
    }

    public T1 this[T2 key]
    {
        get
        {
            return dic2[key];
        }
        set
        {
            dic2[key] = value;
            dic1[value] = key;
        }
    }

    public void Remove(T1 key)
    {
        var value = dic1[key];
        dic1.Remove(key);
        dic2.Remove(value);
    }

    public void Remove(T2 key)
    {
        var value = dic2[key];
        dic2.Remove(key);
        dic1.Remove(value);
    }

    public void Add(T1 key, T2 value)
    {
        dic1.Add(key, value);
        dic2.Add(value, key);
    }
}
```

Comment: That what I just ended up doing. I just wondered if there was a type that did it for me. Guess not.

Comment: Oh, and what happens if T1 and T2 are of the same type?

Comment: @Karlovsky120 When trying to use it, one gets a "call is ambiguous" compiler error.

Comment: Well, that is simply fixed by changing the method names to eg. remove1 and remove2.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need another data structure if values are unique:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<int, string> { { 1, "a" }, { 2, "b" }, { 3, "c" } };
Console.WriteLine(dict[1]); // a

var res = dict.Keys.FirstOrDefault(k => dict[k] == "a");
Console.WriteLine(res); // 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this and it worked:

```
public class customDict<TValue> : Dictionary<int, TValue> where TValue : class
{
    public int this[TValue index]
    {
        get
        {
            var retVal = this.Where(e => e.key == index);
            if (retVal.Count() == 1)
            {
                return retVal.First().Value;
            }else
            {
                return default(TValue);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I used it in this code

```
var x = new customDict<string>();
x.Add(0, "Bubba");
var alwaysWorked= x[0];
var nowWorks= x["Bubba"];
```

Edited...after re-reading.